# Creating mysql many to many query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Ok I'm a beginner at mysql, but I have been trying to create a query for many to many tables.

My curent structure is:

---

### Products

- sku
- product_name
- price
- etc..

---

### Categories

- id
- category

---

### products_categories

- product_id (from sku column)
- category_id

---

How can I query the following:

- All products in a category
- All categories associated with a product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All products in a category**

```
select p.product_name 
from products p
join product_categories pc
on p.sku = pc.product_id
join categories c
on c.id = pc.category_id
where c.category like '%CATEGORY_NAME_HERE%';
```

**All categories associated with a product**

```
select c.category
from category c
join product_categories pc
on c.category_id = pc.category_id
join product p
on p.sku = pc.product_id
where p.product_name like '%PRODUCT_NAME_HERE%';
```